# How to make images appear randomly in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a web page with a button that says "start game". When this button is clicked, 5 images I have downloaded (img1.png...img5.png) must appear randomly, one at a time, every half a second. Here is my code so far, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>

  var rollImagesSchedule;
  var rollImagesCounter;

  function rollImagesAnimation(){
    rollImagesCounter = 0;
    rollImagesSchedule = setInterval(500);
  }

  function rollImages(){
    var imageValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    var imageFile = "img" + imageValue + ".png";

    var theImage = document.getElementById("display");
    theImage.src = imageFile;

    rollImagesCounter = rollImagesCounter + 1;

    if (rollImagesCounter == 10){
      clearInterval(rollImagesSchedule);
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Game</h1>
  <button onClick="rollImagesAnimation()">Start frog game</button>

  <br /><br />

  <img id="display" style='width:200px; height:200px;'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: In real-life/production situations (ie. serving this up as a website in the internet), the first time the image gets loaded the user would experience a noticeable loading state (depending on user's internet connection) and would cause jank in the user experience so it might be worthwhile to pre-load the images.

Comment: I don't need to put this on the internet. I just need to use jpg or png files. They would start blank, then once the button is clicked, begin appearing randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting stuck with the way to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

You can try to create a counter outside `setInterval` function, and nest all of your works inside of it. And the counter should be checked at the top.

```js
function rollImages(){
  var counter = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter === 10) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return;
    }
    
    var imageValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    var imageFile = "img" + imageValue + ".png";

    var theImage = document.getElementById("display");
    theImage.src = imageFile;

    counter++;
  }, 500);
}
```

Then, you can edit the way to catch event `rollImages`:

```
<button onClick="rollImages()">Start frog game</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

My English is not very good, so I might misunderstand your question. Let me answer it according to what I understand.

Your requirement is to randomly display one of the five pictures every 500 milliseconds, right? If so, you can try this idea:

1. Put the src of 5 pictures into an array

```js
var imageSrcs = ["image1","image2","image3","image4","image5"];
```

2. Every 500 milliseconds, execute the following function:

```js
function rollImages(){
          // Randomly generate a random number between 0-4
          int index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
         
          var theImage = document.getElementById("display");
          // Use random numbers as subscripts and take values from the array
          theImage.src = imageSrcs[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the images name files into an array and then setInterval a random number and assign the source of an img html element:

```js
var list = [
  "image1.jpg",
  "image2.jpg",
  "image3.jpg",
];

var i = 0;
function changeImgs() {
  var imageValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length - 1) + 1;
  image.src = list[imageValue];
}

setInterval(function() {
  changeImgs()
}, 2000);

window.onload = changeImgs;
```

```html
<img id="image" class="size">
```

Comment: 1. He asked for the function to start `onClick` and 2. it's every half second but those are minor details